# Ubuntu 20.04: Kernel Panic for clean installation

Tags: upgrade

Im trying to do a clean installation in my laptop Lenovo Ideapad S410p with Nvidia, actually running Ubuntu 18.04 dualboot with official Windows 10 with no issues.

I just create a USB bootable and try to run it, after the GRUB screen I get the attached error message. I try to edit the ubuntu line in that grub to avoid some issues with nvidia and nothing, any help?

Due to restrictions for Covid in my country Im in quarantine and I cant get a clean DVD.

I test the ISO in a Virtualbox and install Ubuntu 20.04 with no issues there.

But my main concern: If I need to do a distribution upgrade, Can I face the same issue with 20.04?

Update: I just add the image with error! 
[image]

Comment: My suggestion, if you can, is wait till late in July when 20.04.1 is released.  Most of the early pains that fill these forums will be worked out by then. And your upgrade will have a greater chance of success.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks! I just add the image